# Find the value of a

Tags: linear-algebra, tangent-line

A straight line with the equation:

$$y = 2x - 2$$

Passes through the x-intercept:
$$\frac{4a^2+1}{4}$$

Find the value of a.

My process:

Since the straight line passes through the line:

$$ 2x - 2 = \frac{4a^2+1}{4}$$
$$ 8x - 8 = {4a^2+1}$$
$$ 8x - 9 = {4a^2}$$
$$ \frac{8x -9}{4} = {a^2}$$
Squareroot the following. Dont know how to squareroot in this site.
$$ \frac{8x -9}{4} = {a}$$

The answer shoud be in numbers as far as I am concerned so I dont think my process is right. Please help. Thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $x$ intercepts occur when $y=0$.

Thus:

$$0=2x-2$$

$$x=1$$

Setting the second equation equal to one:

$$1=\frac{4a^2+1}{4}$$

$$4a^2=3$$

$$a=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

Comment: I looked at the answer and it says that a = 1/2.

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing something I fail to see how that is the correct answer.

Plugging in $1/2$ for $a$ we get $\frac{4\cdot1/4+1}{4}$, which is $2/4$. Plugging this into the original equation we get $-1$ for the $y$ value, which means $1/2$ isn't an $x$-intercept.

Comment: My bad. I am extremely sorry, you are right. I was looking at the wrong page on the answer sheet.

Comment: It's fine, no worries.